# Jetpack Compose Material3 Pull to Refresh functionality

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying to migrate a project from Material2 specs to Material 3 compose library following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#bottom-navigation).

The current LazyColumn in Material2 has integrate Pull to refresh functionality, [found here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/pullrefresh/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pullRefresh(androidx.compose.material.pullrefresh.PullRefreshState,kotlin.Boolean))

However, i did not find any such functionality for Material3.
There is an issue tracker open [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261760718) but they say this functionality will be considered only mid this year, which is too long to wait.

Does anyone have any idea on how this situation should be handled? Pull to refresh is an important flow of our apps user flow, so not having it is not an option.

Should we use `accompanist/swipeToRefresh` even though it is deprecated?

I am not proficient in writing custom compose components yet, so any help in figuring this out would be appreciated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Our team ran into this same problem. Ultimately, we opted to bring the MD2 implementation of the PullToRefresh component into our project as a temporary workaround. Then, we just updated any MD2 references to their MD3 counterparts.

The full MD2 implementation consists of the following files:

- PullRefresh.kt
- PullRefreshIndicator.kt
- PullRefreshIndicatorTransform.kt
- PullRefreshState.kt

This approach was suggested in this [discussion](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262183520#comment2). You can find the op's full solution [here](https://github.com/Omico/androidx-compose-material3-pullrefresh).

Comment: I just don't understand why to make it so difficult to install such library, I ended up simply copy and pasting those files. People like to make things harder for absolutely zero-to-none benefits, time is money. And you just made me save a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like currently there's a dedicated Material3 component for this: PullToRefreshContainer.

See docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/pulltorefresh/package-summary

At the time of writing the api is experimental and I'd expect it to be updated to make it easier to hoist the state out of the UI element, but the example in the docs provides a starting point for migrating. It lacks a callback on refresh starting, which is something you'd have to work around in the interim.